# Google cloud messaging with CCS

Tags: android

I am new to GCM and have a few questions regarding an app implementation. The app should be capable of upstream messaging. So -

1. Do I have to create a server (lets say in Google App engine) which will communicate with GCM. And then GCM will send the message to the app. Or I can do it just with CCS connection and my device can send message to app on another device without a server?
2. Is there a code example of writing server side code which I can use in App Engine? I badly need some tutorial/code implementation on CCS to understand the logic. I dont think android developer site is enough to understand things clearly.

Help appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

Hi Actually I am using http://parse.com to create server and push notification in android.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should always go to the [source and read](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html), as Google provides samples and everything.

About 1 and 2 then it depends if your going to use a third party provider or do everything yourself.

If your making everything yourself then YES you need a server and YES Google provides some code but I've never used it so I can't tell you how much work you have to put in it.

If you just want GCM capabilities but it doesn't have to be Googles, then there is plenty of alternatives out there: [Parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android) and [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/products/mobile-app-engagement#push-messages) to name at least two.

Answer (score 0):

Following link will help to code GCM but it is unidirectional(from third party server to cloud only)
http://avilyne.com/?p=267

Answer (score 0):

Google GCM CSS provides upstream messaging that is from application(http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html), you can send a message. This message will reach the Google server and they will send you the same message to your server, which you have to implement(https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html).Do what you want with it.

If you have to send a message from your server to the client(application), you can send it via your css server or by making a http call to the google gcm http server. They will send the message to the client. You have to handle the received message and can show as a notification or use internally.